# WPF Datagrid Combobox XAML and Codebehind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Since I am a beginner in WPF, I have a question which might be basic in nature.

I have a datagrid which has a combobox.

The xaml which I have written is:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ControlOption" Width="100"
       SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=DataGridComboxBox_Control}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <col:ArrayList>
            <sys:String>Database1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>DataBase2</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I have 3 values which should be there in the drop down of the comboBox.
1. WorkStream1
2. WorkStream2
3. WorkStream3

Now how do I write the codebehind for the ComboxBox.
Please do give me pointers in this. :)

Very much appreciated.

Ashutosh

Comment: your question is not clear, what exactly you want to do in code behind?

Comment: I have made edits to my post sating that there need to be the 3 values in the dropdown of the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, haven't quite understood you. Do you want to replace the itemssource of combobox from code behind?
In this case you can to bind combobox's ItemsSource to property. Like that:

```
<Controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Gender" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Genders}" />
```

and in code behind will be smth like

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> Genders
    {
        get {
            return _genders;
        }
        set { _genders = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Genders"));
        }
    }
```

If you meant smth else, explain please. May be I've understood you in a wrong way

Comment: As I mentioned before. Use binding as for ItemsSource of your Combobox column. ObservableCollection notifies when the collections changes. So, if you want to set new values you can call Genders.Clear() method and add new values (WorksStreams)

Comment: Thanks Artiom :) Got it and needed the same.

Answer (score 0):

use datagrid_PreviewKeyDown function to capture keypressed in grid. if the cell is focused use 
datagrid.BeginEdit() to convert cell from text block to combo box.
i think this will help to solve the issue.